# Devise will not let me sign in or out ( for Chrome only )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

Though occasionally and without any sort of sense, it will work ( but just once ).

If I click log out, I get this :

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-06 11:30:13 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Redirected to http://love.website.dev/
```

And then if I can make it to the login side of things the log returns this :

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-06 12:15:00 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"o8Gb8iJc0hsecretm3EXkwgLnkcSPc6c/iAi8Q=", "user"=>{"email"=>"trip@trip.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}

Redirected to http://love.mywebsite.dev/
Completed 302 Found in 306ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Mind you, this works in IE, Firefox, and Safari.. just Chrome has this issue.

I followed through a trail in Devise and found this line in my `sign_in_out.rb:72`  :

```
users = Devise.mappings.keys.map { |s| warden.user(scope: s, run_callbacks: false) }
```

Which returns :

```
> [nil]
```

Hmm.. so it turns out Warden is not creating a session variable..

```
> session
-> {}
```

But I use Firefox :

```
=> {"warden.user.user.key"=>[[1], "$2a$10$eGalHPmX4ab32HR0VHwHP."],
 "flash"=>
  #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007fb8cbad3fc8
   @closed=false,
   @flashes={:notice=>"Signed in successfully."},
   @now=nil,
   @used=#<Set: {:notice}>>}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really strange answer. I'm sorry this is so weird. But I found out that if I simply change the key I was passing ( yah, the one I've been successfully using for four years with the same app ), then it works.

```
MyApplication.config.session_store :active_record_store,
                 :key => '_new_superfluously_named_session',
```